# Spring Data JPA / Hibernate - findByY(String y) method in @Repository where Y is accessible via object X

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I've got a UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
}
```

where User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'user')
public class User
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserDetails userDetails;
}
```

and UserDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'user_details')
public class UserDetails
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User owner;

    private String name;
}
```

Packages, imports, getters and setters are excluded for cleaner code.

---

Now, how can I find users by their name? Adding this to the UserRepository interface will not work:

```
List<User> findByName(String name);
```

because it throws:

```
No property name found for type User
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
List<User> findByNameOfUserDetails(String name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the Spring Data JPA docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

You'll need something like `findByUserDetailsName(String name)`.
To resolve this ambiguity you can use `_` inside your method name to manually define traversal points. So our method name would be `findByUserDetails_Name(String name)`.